# Dynamically setting src of iframe is throwing "Object doesn't support this property or method" error

Tags: javascript, iframe

Im trying to dynamically set the src of iframe using javascript as follows:

```
<script language="javascript">

function OpenMailTo(mailId) {
    document.getElementById('mailToFrame').src = 'mailto:' + mailId;  // <-- error here
    return false;
}

</script>

<iframe id="mailToFrame" src="" height="0" width="0" style="display:none;"></iframe>
```

It is throwing "Object doesn't support this property or method". Im using IE 9 browser. Even though it is throwing error, it is opening the new mail window (outlook window).

Can anyone please help me in solving this issue.

**EDIT:**

BTW it is throwing error only if debugging is enabled or if disable script debugging is enabled in IE options.

**EDIT:**

This is my calling code

```
<span> test text <a href="#" onclick="OpenMailTo('email@test.com');" >email@test.com</a>
testing.....
</span>
```

**EDIT:**

This is the screenshot of the error:
[image]

Comment: *"Even though it is throwing error, it is opening the new mail window (outlook window)."* That suggests the problem isn't in `OpenMailTo` at all, but rather in the calling code *after* the call to `OpenMailTo` completes (which you haven't shown).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, its breaking in the javascript.

Comment: Why so complicated and not directly: `<a href="mailto:email@test.com;" >email@test.com</a>`? I guess IE complains about `mailto` not being a valid protocol in the source for an iframe.

Comment: @Christoph, i couldnt put it directly, coz we have dirty check in the page. so whe the link is clicked, its pops "do you want to leave the page..." and mailto: also got issues with IE, so i couldnt find any alternatives to overcome it.

Comment: @Harsha then improve the check and make exceptions in the js side, because a mailto in a iframe is the weirdest thing I've seen yet, no wonder IE doesn't like it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the following and it worked

```
function OpenMailTo(mailId) {
  document.getElementById('mailToFrame').setAttribute("src", 'mailto:' + mailId);
  return false;
}
```

Can anyone validate above code, I used setAttribute("src","link goes here"). Is this the correct way of setting src to iframe.